# How to make Google Studio Handle Blank values in my source (google sheet) when creating calculated fields

Tags: looker-studio

I'm trying to create a field in Google Data Studio that would sum 5 different fields (my source), the problem is those values are currently blank (the sheet is reading from another system), but i want to create the field anyway for when the values are feeded in. Google Data Studio is telling me the field cannot be deleted

I've tried to handle with `CASE if X is null then 0...` but this isnt working, when i try to manualy add data into the sheet (the source) it works, but then when i delete it the scorecard i'm using is returning error

This is the code for one of the 5 fields i'm trying create.

The 1 to 5 range is the range of all possible values in the spreadsheet.

Field A:

```
case
    when X IS NULL then 0
    when X = 1 then 1
    when X = 2 then 2
    when X = 3 then 3
    when X = 4 then 4
    when X = 5 then 5
else 0
end
```

Failed to create field. Please try again later... this is when i try to create the field when the values of the fields in the spreadsheet are blanks.

Comment: Are your 5 fields pulling through as metrics or dimensions?

Comment: Metrics... and their type is numbers, and the possible values in the original data source (google sheet) are either blanks or 0 to 5... I'm using these values to calculate their average

Comment: I think your answer is within your own explanation. Once you have some data coming in it will work by the sounds of it. Just as an aside, you could shorten that case statement to case when X in (1,2,3,4,5) then X else 0 end

Comment: Thanks, Bob, but my problem is that the calculated field or the chart using it, where I have the above case statement, is returning an error when my data source (its a column in a google sheet) has only blank values... i need to be live with the report (GDS dashboard) with blank values... This problematic feild might be blank forever ...

Answer (score 2):

## 0) Summary

[`IFNULL`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/10521929) (#1) is the new recommended suggestion; [`NARY_MAX`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7583429) (#2) was the original suggestion:

## 1) Update - Recommend Suggestion ([`IFNULL`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/10521929))

The [01 Apr 2021 Update](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/10331528#apr-1-2021) introduced the [`IFNULL`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/10521929) function which is specifically designed to assign a numeric value to **NULL** values, whereas the original [`NARY_MAX`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7583429) [Calculated Field](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685) below would set the minimum value to 0 which would lead that negative values (such as -1) being be captured as a 0:

```
IFNULL(Field1, 0) + 
IFNULL(Field2, 0) + 
IFNULL(Field3, 0) + 
IFNULL(Field4, 0) + 
IFNULL(Field5, 0)
```

Added a [New Page](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/60c8346b-3539-4a3c-9384-e25e890dd488/page/gVYIC) to the Editable Google Data Studio Report (Embedded [Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JKwalByY5H3yQOf0C6TxBNeBriV6XDNsKS51VWPIvmQ/edit?usp=sharing) Data Source) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image: 7]

## 2) Original Suggestion ([`NARY_MAX`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7583429))

It can be achieved using the [`NARY_MAX`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7583429) function:

```
NARY_MAX(Field1, 0) + NARY_MAX(Field2, 0) + NARY_MAX(Field3, 0) + NARY_MAX(Field4, 0) + NARY_MAX(Field5, 0)
```

***How it works***:
`NARY_MAX` takes the `MAX` value from a range of fields, thus in the above case, when evaluating `NARY_MAX(NULL, 0)`, 0 is greater than `NULL`, thus 0 is preferred in the calculation.

***NULL vs 0***
While a number has a value (negative, 0 or positive), `NULL` is not a value, thus can't be used in a calculation.

[Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/60c8346b-3539-4a3c-9384-e25e890dd488) to demonstrate:

[image: 9]